# With Putty how do you make it act like windows cmd prompt with up arrow presses?

Tags: windows-7, terminal, putty, serial

With Putty I would like to be able to press the up key to cycle through previous commands like Windows cmd prompt. Is there a way to accomplish this with Putty windows on a serial connection?

If not, is there a serial terminal connection program like Putty that does have that functionality?

Comment: That is a functionality of the system you are connecting to, not of Putty. Depending on the system you are connecting to, it may or may not provide this functionality. Try installing or using a different shell on the system you are connecting to.

Comment: The functionality you are seeking is called "command history".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of the up arrow key is something that's determined by what you're connecting to rather than something that PuTTy has control over. If I use it to connect to a Linux server over SSH then it'll behave that way, but if what I'm connecting to doesn't behave that way, it won't.

In such case, you should try and find out if the service or hardware you're connecting to has such functionality.

Comment: Depends on the default shell for the user, so Bash does this for example. Saying "Linux" is a bit deceptive since some minimalistic distros or shells might not support this, even if it is running on Linux.